# Are documents in SP2010 saved directly to MS SQL Database

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, database, sql

When I Upload a document e.g. Word or Excel documents to a document list. Are the files saved directly binary to an SQL database? If yes, could someone give me a url by MS, where I can find further informations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, documents are stored as blobs in the site collection content database (SQL Server). You can read about [document management in the Microsoft blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/02/15/introducing-document-management-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx), and on [database management on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825329%28v=office.14%29.aspx).